# RedBean PHP for master/slave MYSQL databases

Tags: php, mysql, master-slave, redbean

I'm trying to setup a master/slave database for my project.
I want to continue using RedBean as ORM but i've a requirement.

I need to use the Master DB only for writing queries (Insert, Update, Delete) and other Slave(s) database(s) (one or more in the future) just for reading data (Select queries).

Is there any way I can configure RedBean to do this automatically instead to switch database for every single query in my project source code?

Comment: This is usually done through some kind of an sql proxy / load balancer server that splits the operations between the multiple replicas. You really do not want to handle this level of detail in the application layer as you would have to rewrite your application if your infrastructure changes.